# Typescript generators: SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word

Tags: typescript, generator

I am learning some Typescript and use a Trie structure to test some of the concepts, It seems that I don't understand generators well. The mix between typescript and js is not helping.

My search needs to walk a recursive structure, after finding an initial node.

```
    search(prefix: string): Generator<[string, V], undefined, boolean> {
        const findNode = [...]
    enter code here
        function* walkNodes(node: TrieNode<V>,  prefix: string): Generator<[string,V], undefined, boolean> {
            if (node.value != undefined) {
               node.children.forEach( (child, key) => 
                    yield * walkNodes(child, prefix + key)
                )
            } else {
                yield [prefix, node.value!]
            }
            return undefined
        }

        const startNode = findNode(prefix, this) 
        return walkNodes(startNode!, prefix)
    }
```

When this is translated I have an error, that I understand but not sure how to avoid.

```
return yield* walkNodes(child, prefix + key);
                                   ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:355:18)
```

At this stage I am not sure what is going on, how can use yield inside an object?

Thanks.

Comment: it seems it highlights the wrong place of code because of unknown reason, maybe some custom transformation. I would try to comment out pieces of code, and try to find the piese where problem is gone

Comment: `return yield` seems like an odd transformation of this code. But there isn't enough code for me to actually try compiling it.

Comment: Oh, also - you cannot use `yield` in the callback for `forEach`. It's only valid in generator functions and the callback is definitely not that.

Comment: here the full code: https://github.com/pegerto/tstrie/blob/main/src/index.ts#L48-L60

Comment: yes, removing the for each callback and setting   "downlevelIteration": true seems to help

Comment: @VLAZ is correct. Therefore as you're using `yield` and `yield *` use `for..of` to iterate over the array instead of `.forEach`